# If condition inside ggplot

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2

Why `if` statement does not work inside `ggplot` function but works as a last line:

```
index <- 1
```

This works:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+
  geom_line()+
  if(index==1) geom_point()
```

However, when I move the `if` statement, it does not work:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+
  if(index==1) geom_point()+  #or if(index==1) {geom_point()}+
  geom_line()
```

Is there anyway to use `if` statement inside `ggplot`, not in the last line? I know I can do the following, but I am curious if I can use it inside `ggplot`:

```
p <-  ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+
      geom_line()

if(index==1) p <- p + geom_point()
```

Comment: Put it in curly braces, i.e. `{if(index==1) geom_point()} + `

Comment: Just put your assignment inside the if statement: `if (index==1) p <- p + geom_point()`

Comment: Just tried @joran's suggestion and it works: `{if(index==1) geom_point()}`.

Comment: @joran I was exactly looking for this. Do you want to put as an answer, I looked everywhere.

Comment: @Soheil No, someone found a good duplicate with both approaches.